# How to find the number of nodes and edges in the TREEPLOT function to MATLAB/OCTAVE GNU?

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

How to find the number of nodes and edges in the TREEPLOT function to MATLAB/OCTAVE GNU?

Create treeplot and count markers and segments connected in the TREEPLOT.

```
clf;  
treeplot([2 4 2 0 6 4 6]);  
% Plot a simple tree plot
```

Comment: Note a generalised answer, but the number of nodes will be the number of points in the vector, and the number of edges will be the number of non-zero entries. So if you have `v=[2 4 2 0 6 4 6]` then `nNodes = numel(v)` and `nEdges = nnz(v)`. If you really want to parse the treeplot specifically, then you will have to access `XData` and `YData` from `get(gca, 'Children')`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to determine properties as number od nodes, edges, trees, ... just by parsing the array.

Assuming the array is well formatted and names *trep*:

```
properties.totalNodes=numel(trep);
properties.totalEdges=numel(trep)-sum(trep==0);
properties.separateTrees=sum(trep==0);

if sum(trep==0)>1
for zz=1:sum(trep==0)
    mask=find(~[0 trep 0]);
    nonZeroSeq=diff(mask);
    properties.(['tree' num2str(zz)]).Nodes=nonZeroSeq(zz+1);
    properties.(['tree' num2str(zz)]).Edges=nonZeroSeq(zz+1)-1;
end
end
```

**Disclaimer**: i did not have time to *validate* this code for every case, so it may return wrong results. Manually double check case-by-case

---

Alternatively a **digraph** function can be used instead of **treeplot**.

```
dg=digraph(trep(trep~=0),find(trep));
plot(dg);
```

The digraph object dg carries 2 properties, Edges and Nodes and can be accessed by:

```
dg.Edges
dg.Nodes
```